# SQLite how to update a column which belongs to a multi-column index

Tags: sqlite, indexing

Say I have a index (id, name) and want to execute a query like:

```
update <table> set name='new name' where name='old name'
```

Then I got error like:

```
Query Error: columns id, name are not unique Unable to fetch row.
```

What is that error? And how can I update that column without getting error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you could show the contents of `<table>`, at least all the rows with `name = 'new name'` or `name = 'old name'`.

However, the most logical assumption is that there already exist in your table two rows with the same `id`, one of them having the value `'new name'` and the other having the value `'old name'` in the `name` field.  If that's true, and you run this `UPDATE` then the results would violate any `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` index on that combination of fields.

Comment: you are right. I didn't get it that "columns id, name are not unique" mean not unique in that table.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that in sqlite, the `WHERE` clause has to return one unique row.

Change your SQL to:

```
update <table> set name='new name' where id='id' and name='old name'
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer.  I'm not sure how much use a database would be if it only allowed queries that returned a single row.  I don't think that's the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is hard to understand.

In more detail it could say:

```
Query Error: columns id, name would be not unique after the update operation
```